# ASP slider control for pdf and powerpoint presentations

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm looking for a control(s) which allow me to nest and slide pdf and powerpoint presentation slides on the web page (like google docs does). Can somebody recommend me such controls ?

I know that one way of doing what I want is to convert slides to images and usage of control like ASP.NET AJAX SlideShow Extender for previewing images, but I would like to find more sophisticated tools.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution for including *PDF* or *PowerPoint* documents on pages without installing any extensions. I've used [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) with [Lytebox](http://dolem.com/lytebox/) dialog box. Solution is simple and looks as follows:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/lytebox.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lytebox.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.mydoc.pdf&embedded=true"
   rel="lyteframe" 
   title="Make preview" 
   data-lyte-options="width:800 height:500 scrolling:no">
 Make preview
</a>
```

[image]

Regards